# MVC Session loses value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session

On my localhost server `Session["Culture"]` variable always store the proper value. 
But on my external server, the same session variable (`Session["Culture"]`) sometimes lose value and become null. Why it is happen? And how to resolve it?

Part of a `global.asax.cs` file:

```
    protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
        {

            CultureInfo ci = (CultureInfo)this.Session["Culture"];
            if(ci == null){
                //breakpoint
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

It is obvious that session cannot be shared between server A and server B.
 My problem is rather different - in a nutshell- the same application, but: 
1) on server A (localhost) `Session["Culture"]` works **properly** and it **always** store some information.
2) on server B (external) `Session["Culture"]` work nice but always after random time lose value and become `null`

Comment: Is the session timing out on the other server? That could be the reason that `Session["Culture"]` becomes `null`

Comment: do you have only one server? sounds like multip server inproc mode

Comment: @GregBurghardt - it becomes `null` sometimes after 1 min and sometimes after 30 min. So I don't think so it is timed out. @Onur TOPAL - I have 2 external servers, and what is strange, there is the same situation. Only at localhost everything works perfectly.

Comment: Session is not shared between servers unless you are using something like the SQL Session provider.  The session in server A's memory will not exist on server B's memory.  You are seeing it disappear because sometimes your request is going to server A (where you have set the variable) and sometimes the request is going to server B (which has no idea about that variable on server A).  Localhost works fine because its a single web server.

Comment: so it is your problem in inproc mode server keeps session in the memory and it is not shareable just check here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586(v=vs.140).aspx

Comment: @Tommy look please at my edit. I don't want to share session. I have a problem with different behaviour of the same variable at 2 different servers.

Comment: You stated that you have 2 external servers, this typically means that you have your site load balanced.  That is where the comment came from.

Comment: Also, when you state you only have one external server, are you using a host of any kind (GoDaddy, etc) or is it actually your server?  Many host providers, even when you get space on one of their servers, still have your application load balanced (spread across multiple machines).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In-process session state is subject to being cleared any time, as sessions are ended when the appdomain is recycled.

You can mitigate this some by using an external session storage mechanism, such as the state service, or a database provider. You can also build your own session state provider.

However; you should still treat session state as only somewhat less volatile than cache, if you want it to be robust; always check for null, and reset the values if so.

If sessions are expiring that quickly on one server, I would look into why that might be. Something may be causing recycles improperly.

Addition: I see you are using multiple servers; in-process session state also cannot handle this. The above advice can help there, too.

Comment: thanks for reply. To be clear - I don't use multiple servers, please look at my edit. I found that Session variable on external server behaves different than on localhost and that's why I created question. As I understood, problem is with `in-proc` session state? And there is only one solution for that - to change session storage mechanism? Regards

Comment: @whoah the first parts of my answer still apply.